# Referencing variable in path using Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am fairly new to Python and have always used it in ArcGIS Pro.
I have now moved to PyCharm and feel I am missing some of the basics.

It's pretty simple I am just wanting just wanting to make the contour height on the end of my output path a variable

Segment0_Contour_**10m**

Could anyone indicate how to do so?

i.e I would like it to be whatever the contour interval is set to, so I don't have to change it manually.

Code below.

```py
Segment0 = os.path.join(mypath, "SPLIT0.tif")

#Update contour interval below
ContourInterval= 10

arcpy.ddd.Contour(Segment0, os.path.join(mypath, "Segment0_Contour_10m"), ContourInterval, 0, 1, "CONTOUR", None)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do variable interpolation in Python.  My preferred way is to use the `format()` function on a string, which will look for `{}` items in the string to replace with the list of variables passed to the `format()` function.

In your case, replace:

```
"Segment0_Contour_10m"
```

with:

```
"Segment0_Contour_{}m".format(ContourInterval)
```

You can include more information about how to handle the interpolation between the `{}`, but for a single integer to be included in a string, nothing further is necessary.

(NB:  This isn't really a GIS Stack Exchange question, as it is a Python programming question with nothing GIS-specific to it.  It probably would have been better to post it on Stack Overflow, instead.)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a version of Python > 3.6 you can also use the [pathlib library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which is more intuitive to use in combination with [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```py
from pathlib import Path

Segment0 = os.path.join(mypath, "SPLIT0.tif")

for in interval in list_interval #I guess the interval are stored in a list
    segment = Path(mypath)/f"Segment0_Contour_{interval}m"
    arcpy.ddd.Contour(Segment0, segment, ContourInterval, 0, 1, "CONTOUR", None)
```

Comment: Thank you - worked a treat!!